# How to get a variable from browser with cucumber/pioneer/selenium?

Tags: testing, cucumber

I have this script that looks like this:

```
this.When(/^I should be logged in$/, function(value){
    console.log('> ', this.driver.executeScript('return "test"'));
});
```

And the output of console.log is

```
>  { then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

Instead of

```
"> test"
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
this.When(/^I should be logged in$/, function(value){
 var result = this.driver.executeScript('return "test"');
    console.log('> ', result );
});
```

Comment: Same thing... Anyway it should not change the behavior based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the solution

```
    var result = this.driver.executeScript('return "test"');
    result.then(function(value){
        console.log(value)
    })
```

Because I think it uses async in order to communicate with the driver.